Is it possible to hide the Developer Phone Number in the Chrome Webstore page?
I am wondering how is it possible to hide the phone number of the developer on the Chrome Webstore extension page.
It has already an email, I don't want to show my phone number.
Mu extension is for my company, so is a "trader account"
I followed the link about the Google payments profile, but I can't choose to hide th phone number.

I have been in contact with Google Chrome Web Store Support and this was their answer:

For some extensions, it is possible that they have previously
identified themselves as a trader before the Europe’s Digital Services
Act went into effect on February 17, 2024. That's why their phone
number is not visible yet. After that, new and existing traders are
required to do the trader verification as well. Some extensions might
have not done it, but they still need to do it, or else, their
extension will be disabled at a certain time.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to hide the phone number after
verification, unless you will set your account as a non-trader
account.
Verification via call is not yet supported. The trader verification
currently supports verification via SMS OTP. We are continually
working on improvements to the Chrome Web Store, and feedback from
developers like you are invaluable and I've relayed your concerns to
our product team. While I cannot guarantee immediate changes, we are
certainly looking into it.
Thank you for your understanding and patience. We genuinely value the
contributions you and other developers bring to the Chrome ecosystem.

As we started to receive spam messages etc. on the private number that was published, we ultimately used a random prepaid phone number for the verification process, hoping that Google urgently fixes this issue.
